# GaxiosError: Internal error Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-api-nodejs-client, google-appengine-node

Every week my Google App Engine throws an error:

GaxiosError: Internal error
.Gaxios._request ( /workspace/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:129 )

It happens once or twice per week, and takes my application (NodeJS) down for ~8 minutes. Then it gets back up until the next time the error comes.

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: As is mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68977151/google-app-engine-nodejs-app-stops-after-30-min/68978912#68978912) there are [good strategies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_uptime) to avoid the downtime of your instance, there you can find some other related ideas. Also, maybe you have a deferred task stuck running as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371556/google-app-engine-nodejs-application-goes-down-over-night).

Comment: Please share any piece of code that [might generate this error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from your `gaxios.js` file and the full error lines (unless this is all you get).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 0):

That´s all I get from the error.
It seems that the error is coming from the line 129 in gaxios.js, but I couldn´t debug it.

[image][image]